# Ошибка БД в битриксе при проверке сайта в админке

Tags: mysql, битрикс

При проверке сайта на Bitrix возникает следующая ошибка:

> 2015-Dec-28 08:16:44 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Fail
>   ALTER TABLE `b_iblock_element_property` MODIFY `VALUE` text NOT NULL ;
>   Структура базы данных имеет ошибки (нет таблиц: 0, нет полей: 0, поля отличаются: 1, нет индексов: 0). Всего 1, автоматически могут быть исправлены: 0.

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно изменить тип поля value с varchar(255) на text

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, можно сделать и без `phpMyAdmin`:

Шаг 1. Заходите в `Консоль SQL` в админке Битрикса

Шаг 2. Выполняем там ряд команд:

```
# Делаем резервную копию
create table b_iblock_element_property_backup like b_iblock_element_property;
insert into b_iblock_element_property_backup select * from b_iblock_element_property;
# Превращаем NULL в пустую строчку
update b_iblock_element_property set VALUE = '' where VALUE IS NULL;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,
    SELECT * FROM b_iblock_element_property where VALUE is NULL

Comment: не привело к нужному результату.( таких строк нет)

Comment: А если делать `ALTER TABLE b_iblock_element_property MODIFY VALUE text NOT NULL ;` в консоли, выполняется?

Comment: Нужно изменить тип поля value с varchar(255) на text

Comment: Так выполняется или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала дамп базы, а потом

```
UPDATE b_iblock_element_property SET VALUE = '' WHERE ISNULL(VALUE)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Нет там таких 
    SELECT * FROM b_iblock_element_property where VALUE is NULL